# In stored procedure %Rowtype is not working while deploying

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, db2-luw

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CAS.ROWTYPECHECK ( P_APPLICATION_REC  TAPPLICATION%ROWTYPE )
IS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO "CAS"."VAPPLICATION"
    VALUES P_APPLICATION_REC;
END;
```

But I'm getting one error while deploying.

Deploy CAS.ROWTYPECHECK

> Running
>   CAS.ROWTYPECHECK - Deploy started.
>   Create stored procedure returns SQLCODE: -104, SQLSTATE: 42601.
>   CAS.ROWTYPECHECK: 1: An unexpected token "%" was found following "ON_REC
>   TAPPLICATION".  Expected tokens may include:  ",".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.16.53
>   An unexpected token "%" was found following "ON_REC  TAPPLICATION".  Expected tokens may include:  ",".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.16.53
>   CAS.ROWTYPECHECK - Deploy failed.
>   CAS.ROWTYPECHECK - Roll back completed successfully.

DBMS is DB2 V9.1.

I tried using:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE <Sechma>.<ProcedureName> 
  (<Record> <table/VIEW>%ROWTYPE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Db2 for LUW 9.1 did not have the Oracle compatibility feature, which was added since v9.7, so you cannot use the PL/SQL dialect. Moreover, the `CREATE OR REPLACE` syntax or row types were not supported either.

If you wish to use these features, upgrade to a supported version of Db2.